# d3.js get selected nodes and apply color for all the selected nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js for my graphs. To select a node, user will double click on the particular node. My program will change the opacity to 0.1 of the selected node to show that a node is selected. In the same way, a user can select many nodes where the opacity will be changed accordingly. The New requirement is to apply color for all the selected nodes(opacity = 0.1). For that i need to get all the nodes which has the opacity = 0.1. I am working as like this.

```
 node.style("fill", function (o) {
                    debugger;
                    if (o.name == selectednode.name) {

                        o.colorname = color;
                        return color;

                    } else {

                        return o.colorname;
                    }
                });
```

This will change only the color of the last selected node. i need to apply color of all the nodes where its opacity is 0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
var selectedNodes = nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d3.select(this).style("opacity") == 0.1;
});
selectedNodes.style("fill", newColor).style("opacity", "1");
```

Demo:

Double click nodes to select. Then, click *Highlight Selected* button.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);
var data = [{
  x: 100,
  y: 70
}, {
  x: 200,
  y: 200
}, {
  x: 300,
  y: 70
},{
  x: 150,
  y: 250
}, {
  x: 320,
  y: 170
}, {
  x: 380,
  y: 250
}]
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
  return d.x
}).attr("cy", function(d) {
  return d.y
}).attr("r", 12).on("dblclick", function() {
  d3.select(this).style("opacity", "0.1");
});

function highlightSelected() {
  var selectedNodes = nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d3.select(this).style("opacity") == 0.1;
  });
  selectedNodes.style("fill", "green").style("opacity", "1");
}
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
}
circle {
  fill: red;
}
input {
  position:absolute;
  left: 385px;
  top: 13px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="button" onclick="highlightSelected()" value="Highlight selected" />
</div>
```